# Why not make css margin it is ignored

Tags: html, css

Why `margin-left:0;` does not work? please help me.

[image]

Comment: It probably does work, but above it you are overriding it with another rule: `margin-left: 280px;`. Turn off that rule and see if the margin becomes 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style for `#page-info dl` is applied after the `@media ...` style. The style who is applied as the last, overrides the previously setted.

Comment: margin-left: 0; line in 2199 to override margin-left line: 280px; on line 324 instead?

Comment: I was wrong when it is not written in the css file. Thank you!